# Send accents to mvc controller via ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, encode, diacritics

I am writting an MVC app which uses AJAX to send and return data to/from controller. I use Brazilian-Portuguese to write info on text boxes, like *Hidróxido de alumínio* and then send´em to controller via ajax. The point is text goes truncated, like *HidrÃ³xido de alumÃnio*....

Here goes part of my code:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "/Prescricoes/AddToBin",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                Descricao: medposologia,
                Via: $("#Vias option:selected").val(),
                DVia: $("#Vias option:selected").text(),
                CodigoPrescricao: $("#CodigoPrescricao").val()
            },
            success:
                function (data) {
                    if (data === "ERRO!") {
                        alert("Ocorreu um erro ao adicionar esta linha à prescrição.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    seeBin();
                }
        });
```

*medposologia* is the string that is junked. Here goes part of the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddToBin (PrescricaoSaidaBIN bin, string descricao, int? via, string dvia ,int codigoPrescricao )
    {
        DetalhePrescricao detalheprescricao = new DetalhePrescricao();

        detalheprescricao.DVia = dvia;
        detalheprescricao.CodigoPrescricao = codigoPrescricao;
        detalheprescricao.Descricao = descricao;
        detalheprescricao.Via = via;

        string resultado = "OK";

        try
        {
            bin.AddItem(detalheprescricao);
        }
        catch {
            resultado = "ERRO!";
        }

        return Json(resultado);
    }
```

The string *descricao* receives *medposologia* already junked!

How to send text with accent and other character in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var data = {
    Via: $("#Vias option:selected").val(),
    Descricao: medposologia,
};
```

and

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "/Prescricoes/AddToBin",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success:
                function (data) {
                    if (data === "ERRO!") {
                        alert("Ocorreu um erro ao adicionar esta linha à prescrição.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    seeBin();
                }
        });
```

end please use english names

Comment: Tnx for your answer. I got another problem: can´t use JSON.stringify... I have tried before, but I get a message error: "JSON is not defined"... I have tried json2.js with no success...

Comment: So I´m still getting mad on this. If someone knows the walkthrough I´ll appreciate!